# For loop in python while updating multiple list indexes?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I am a little bit new to python. I have completed my program of having a quiz of 15 questions, get 5 random of the 15 and print questions one by one to the user. Each question has 4 possible answers.

The program works fine but instead of writing a block of code for each question I would like to loop through all 5 random questions and make it do the same thing as each individual block of code for each question. I am used to Java and it looks like this just doesn't work quite the same so I have commented a poor attempt at the for loop.

I am just trying to make it more efficient so any tips or guidance is helpful. I do not request full answer to my problem. Thanks

```
#Print statement displaying a welcome message
print("***WELCOME TO THE RANDOM QUIZ***\n")

#Importing random library to use the random module
import random

#Creates a list with all 15 questions
questions = ['What is the capital city of Ireland?', 'What is the capital city of France?',
            'What is the capital city of Germany?', 'What is the capital city of Romania?',
            'What is the capital city of Russia?', 'What is the capital city of Belgium?',
            'What is the capital city of Switzerland?','What is the capital city of Egypt?',
            'What is the capital city of Japan?','What is the capital city of China?',
            'What is the capital city of Thailand?','What is the capital city of Brazil?',
            'What is the capital city of Argentina?','What is the capital city of Bolivia?',
            'What is the capital city of Mexico?']

#Creates a list with the answers for each of the 15 individual questions
possible_answers = ['a) Portlaoise | b) Waterford | c) Dublin | d) Galway ', 'a) Paris | b) Lyon | c) Nantes | d) Tolouse ',
                    'a) Frankfurt | b) Munich | c) Berlin | d) Dusseldorf ', 'a) Bucharest | b) Constanta | c) Galati | d) Sibiu ',
                    'a) Moscow | b) St.Petersburg | c) Novosirbirsk | d) Sochi ', 'a) Ghent | b) Bruges | c) Brussels | d) Antwerp ',
                    'a) Zurich | b) Geneva | c) Basel | d) Bern ', 'a) Cairo | b) Alexandria | c) Luxor | d) Giza ',
                    'a) Osaka | b) Yokohama | c) Nagoya | d) Tokyo ', 'a) Beijing | b) Shenzhen | c) Shanghai | d) Fuangzhou ',
                    'a) Bangkok | b) Chiang Mai | c) Pattaya | d) Hat Yai ', 'a) Rio de Janeiro | b) Sao Paolo | c) Salvador | d) Brasilia ',
                    'a) Mendoza | b) Rosario | c) Buenos Aires | d) Cordoba ', 'a) Santa Cruz de la Sierra | b) La Paz | c) El Alto | d) Oruro ',
                    'a) Mexico City | b) Guadalajara | c) Tijuana | d) Merida ']

#Creates a list with the right answers for each of the 15 individual questions
answers = ["Dublin","Paris","Berlin","Bucharest","Moscow","Brussels","Bern","Cairo","Tokyo","Beijing","Bangkok",
            "Brasilia","Buenos Aires","La Paz","Mexico City"]

#Creates variable and assigns the value of 5 which represents the number of random questions we need out of the possible 15
num_of_rand_q = 5

#This variable is created to keep track of the number of right answers by the user
right_q_count = 0

#Assign randomly selected question to a variable
list_of_rand_q = random.sample(questions, num_of_rand_q)


"""
In this operation we match the randomly selected question with the same question in the 'questions' list
to get its original index and assign the index value to a variable. This will help us later on to get the
answer of the exact question by using its original index value as indexes of each question and respective
answer match in both 'questions' and 'answers' lists. We do this for all 5 randomly selected questions.
"""
q_one_index = questions.index(list_of_rand_q[0])
q_two_index = questions.index(list_of_rand_q[1])
q_three_index = questions.index(list_of_rand_q[2])
q_four_index = questions.index(list_of_rand_q[3])
q_five_index = questions.index(list_of_rand_q[4])

"""
#Creating list of indexes so we can loop through them 
q_indexes = [q_one_index, q_two_index, q_three_index, q_four_index, q_five_index]

#Attempted for loop
i = 0
for i in list_of_rand_q[i]:
    print(list_of_rand_q[i])
    print(possible_answers[questions.index(list_of_rand_q[i])], "\n")
    answer_1 = input("Type the city name of which you think it's the capital! \n")

    if answer_1 in answers:
        print('Well done! This is the right answer!')
        right_q_count += 1
    else:
        print('It is the wrong answer...The right answer is actually : ', answers[q_indexes[i]])
"""


#First Question and same as other 4
#Print statement to ask the random question
print(list_of_rand_q[0])
#Print statement to display all 4 possible answers respective to the question
print(possible_answers[questions.index(list_of_rand_q[0])], "\n")
#We ask the user to type the capital city and store the user's input in the answer variable
answer = input("Type the city name of which you think it's the capital! \n")

#If statement checks if user's input matches the value in the answers list
if answer in answers:
    #If statement is true prints a message
    print('Well done! This is the right answer!\n')
    #right_q_count variable stores the number of right answers and we increment it everytime the answer given is right
    right_q_count += 1
#If the if statement is not true and user gets wrong answer then perform 'else'
else:
    #Prints a message and tells the user which is the right answer
    print('It is the wrong answer...The right answer is actually : ', answers[q_one_index], "\n")


#Print statement tells the user how many questions he got right out of the possible 5
print("You got ", right_q_count , "answers right out of 5!" )
```

Comment: Regardless of the solution you end up with, this is nasty: `for i in list_of_rand_q[i]` - you're telling Python that `i` should get assigned each value of `list_of_rand_q[i]`. So, while the loop is changing `i`, you were using it to index a list with its previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `zip` the three lists together to iterate through them simultaneously. Also, you should do `random.sample` of the zipped lists to avoid doing too much indexing. Usually, that many calls to `.index` is a code smell.

```
triplets = list(zip(questions, possible_answers, answers)

num_of_rand_q = 5
right_q_count = 0
list_of_rand_q = random.sample(triplets, num_of_rand_q)

for question, choices, answer in list_of_rand_q:
    print(question)
    print(choices, "\n")

    guess = input("Type the city name of which you think it's the capital! \n")

    if guess == answer:
        print('Well done! This is the right answer!\n')
        right_q_count += 1
    else:
        print('It is the wrong answer...The right answer is actually : ', answer, "\n")

print("You got ", right_q_count , "answers right out of 5!" )
```

As you can see, it's also a bit more intuitive as you don't need to do all that subscripting.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware I could zip up the three lists. This already looks like a much better approach for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should look something like this:

```
for question in list_of_rand_q:
    print(question)
```

or in another situation:

```
sum = 0
for number in range(0,n):
    sum = sum + number
```

In python, the first variable (question or number in the cases above) is the temporary name of the objects found as the for loop iterates through the second structure (list_of_rand_q or range).

In other words, there is no need to give the index of the question in the list when printing the question as the for loop has already located and created a temporary reference to the question.